# Un employed wife uk visit refused

Tags: visas, uk

My husband is studying online in a British university in London while working in the Middle East.

He applied a UK visa for us with the kids to visit the UK for only ten days for a course and some short sightseeing; we were planning to visit Paris later for 3 days and come back home.

Unfortunately the application has been refused. The reasons are: I’m unemployed although I have traveled with my husband several times to Europe and he paid everything for me. And they mentioned the weak ties and an unclear bank account.

So what is the solution for this?

Comment: The refusal notices contain important information. Please scan them, black out personal information such as names, and post as part of your question.

Comment: Just "unemployment" is not a reason to deny a visa. You may check why "unemployed" was relevant in your case. Lack of funds? Wrong visa? Missing documentation? [Do not assume officer will know your status and what you are doing is 100% obvious].